# Generate Typescript ES6 Map with OpenAPI Generator

Tags: typescript, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin, openapi-generator-cli

I'm using the OpenAPI Generator ([typescript-angular](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-angular), but I'm also having the same issue with all other typescript generators) to generate models from a OpenAPI specification that includes:

```
name:
  type: object
  additionalProperties:
    type: string
```

In my typescript model, this generates a field `name: { [key: string]: string; };`. I'd rather have `name: Map<string, string` however, but even when enabling `<supportsES6>true</supportsES6>` the generator does not generate a `Map`.

Using the [java](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java) generator without any further configuration creates a `Map` as required, so I'm pretty confident something is up with the typescript-* generators.

What am I doing wrong - or is it just not supposed to work, even though the documentation explicitly lists the `Map` type as supported?